# Create a new method at run-time

Tags: c#

I want to learn the neat trick of creating a method on the fly with a signature that some client code wants. Just like `System.Delegate.BeginInvoke`, `EndInvoke` and `Invoke` methods.

I am looking inside the `System.Delegate` class for these methods but I can't find them (except for `DynamicInvoke`, which isn't fun because it dynamically dispatches calls to late bound methods anyway), so obviously these methods are made at run-time.

I'm scratching my head as to how, if I had to implement such a thing, I would do. I am thinking aloud:

1) Code DOM won't work because I am not interested in constructing a new assembly. I just want to add a new method to a class within the same assembly.

2) Good old reflection will work just fine. I can get to creating a new `MethodInfo` that has the same parameters as the client code specifies, but then how do I get this new `MethodInfo` thingy to show up in my class as a method?

Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: Have you looked at DynamicMethod?

Comment: Your understand of delegates is incorrect.

Comment: @leppie I'm curious and open to learning more. Please tell me what in my understanding about delegates is wrong. I'd to learn and fix things, if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is to use the `System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod` class. To see an example at work, please visit [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod.aspx).

A big thanks to Jon Skeet for guiding me in the right direction. See the comments to this question.